# msgBox when i edit in a specifically range

Tags: google-apps-script

Well, basically what I would like to do is:

Example:

Range: D7:J30

When there was any edit in this interval, a msgBox would appear for the editor, however, only in cases where something was inserted, not when it was deleted.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Try it with an onEdit trigger.

Comment: So, did you get an answer after all? It's not exactly a good thing to ask questions, get answers, and disappear without any feedback. To say the least.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the task is a bit tricky. `onEdit()` trigger doesn't recognise inserting cells. It's need an installable `onChange()` trigger.

To install the trigger put this function in Script Editor and run it:

```
function set_trigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('alert')
    .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
    .onChange()
    .create();
}
```

Then put in Script Editor the next function:

```
function alert(e) {
  var sheet = e.source;.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() != 'Sheet1') return; // if the sheet name not 'Sheet1' do nothing

  var range  = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var top    = range.getRow();
  var bottom = range.getLastRow();
  var left   = range.getColumn();
  var right  = range.getLastColumn();

  if (      top < 7 
              || 
    left < 4  ||  right > 10
              || 
          bottom > 30       ) return; // ;)

  if (range.getValues().flat().filter(String).length == 0) return; // if the range is empty do nothing
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Something was changed');
}
```

After that if you try to add (to write or insert) something into any cell/cells within the range 'D7:J30' (on sheet 'Sheet1') you will get the message:

[image]